# Minimum of Integral relation via Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality

Tags: analysis

Let's consider the quantity

$G=\int_0^r f^2(t)dt\int_0^r g^2(t)dt-(\int_0^r f(t)g(t)dt)^2$

which is nonnegative by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

I am trying to find inequality conditions (bounds) concerning $f$ and $g$  functions, e.g $0<a\le f(t)\le b, 0<c\le g(t)\le d$, in order to impose $G>l>0$ and calculate that lower bound $l$. I can only find negative bounds $l$ and never positive ones, e.g $G\ge ra^2rc^2-(rdb)^2=r^2(a^2c^2-d^2b^2)$, which is negative. In this case, we cannot find a positive lower bound.

I want to impose some conditions on $f,g$ depending on $r$, and then calculate a lower bound $l(r)$, which depends on $r$.

Comment: You have Cauchy-Schwarz wrong.  It would say $$\left(\int_0^r f^2(t)\; dt \int_0^r g^2(t)\; dt \right)^{1/2} - \int_0^r f(t) g(t)\; dt \ge 0$$

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to square the second term of G

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have $G=0$ if $f$ is a constant multiple of $g$.  So in order to get a positive lower bound, you'll need a condition that rules out $f$ being a constant multiple of $g$.  Your $a \le f \le b$, $c \le g \le d$ can't do that (e.g. both $f$ and $g$ could be constants).